# Given the equation $8CC^T=2I_4$, deduce $C^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

The following was an exercise in my exam:

> Let $C$ be a $4 \times 4$ matrix with nonzero determinant. If $$8CC^T=2I_4$$ then $C$ is invertible and $$C^{-1} = \frac{1}{16}C^T$$

I was wondering: how to I get to this conclusion?

Comment: Ummm... why isn't the equation $4 C C^T = I_4$?

Comment: I think the question should read $\color{red}{\frac{1}{8}}CC^T=2I_4$ instead, i.e. $CC^T=16I$.

Comment: Question looks incorrect, after fixing it, see what happens when you left multiply $C$ to both sides of the equation involving $C^{-1}$

Answer (score 1):

We have $C\cdot 4C^T=I$. By uniqueness of the inverse in the group $GL_4(K)$ we know that $4C^T$ is the inverse of $C$.

Edit: Indeed, the scalar is not $\frac{1}{16}$, because otherwise the equation should have been $\frac{1}{8}CC^T=2I_4$.

Comment: I believe that there is an error in this question ... from $8CC^T=2I_4$, we can only deduce that $C^{-1}=4C^T.$